# Basic Form validation function checkRadio() is not posting error message

Tags: javascript, html, forms, function, validation

I am javascript newbie, I am self learning on line home tutorials.
My Javacript tutorial asks me to try out basic form code.

But the **function checkRadio()** is not posting error message!(if radio buttons Not checked - then post error message)

The **function checkEmail()** does correctly post error message.

I have checked syntax many times. Can you spot error/s please?

Thank you

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<HTML>
    <HEAD>
        <TITLE>Javascript and Forms</TITLE>

        <SCRIPT LANGUAGE = "Javascript">

        function validate() {

            var emailError = checkEmail();
            var radioError = checkRadio();
            var dropdownError = checkDropdown();
            var checkboxError = checkCheckbox();

        }




        function checkEmail(){

            var email = document.frmOne.email.value;
            if(email==""){
                document.getElementById("email_error").innerHTML = "No Email Adress";
                return false;
            }
            else{
                document.getElementById("email_error").innerHTML = "";
                return true;
            }




        }

        function checkRadio(){

            var payment = "";
            var len = document.frmone.payment.length;
            var i;

            for(i = 0;i<len;i++){
                if (document.frmone.payment[i].checked){
                    payment = document.frmone.payment[i].value;
                    break;
                }
            }
            if(payment == ""){
                document.getElementById("radio_error").innerHTML = "No payment Option Selected";
                return false;
            }
            else{
                document.getElementById("radio_error").innerHTML = "";
                return true;
            }
        }







        </SCRIPT>
    </HEAD>

    <BODY>

        <FORM NAME="frmOne" ACTION="" METHOD="POST">

        <P>
            EMAIL: <INPUT TYPE="text" NAME="email" VALUE="" PLACEHOLDER="Email Address"> 
            <SPAN STYLE=color:red ID="email_error"></SPAN>
        </P>

        <P>
            Payment Options:
            <INPUT TYPE="Radio" Name="payment" Value="CC">Credit Card
            <INPUT TYPE="Radio" Name="payment" Value="DC">Debit Card
            <INPUT TYPE="Radio" Name="payment" Value="PP">PayPal 
            <SPAN STYLE=color:red ID="radio_error"></SPAN>
        </P>

        <P>
        Where did you hear about us?
        <SELECT NAME="hear">
            <OPTION Value="None">None</OPTION>
            <OPTION Value="paper">Newspaper</OPTION>
            <OPTION Value="tv">Television</OPTION>
            <OPTION Value="mouth">Word of Mouth</OPTION>
            <OPTION Value="seach">Search Engine</OPTION>
        </SELECT>
         <SPAN STYLE=color:red ID="dropdown_error"></SPAN>
        </P>

        <P>
            <LABEL FOR="CB1">Terms and Conditions</LABEL>
            <INPUT TYPE="Checkbox" Name="terms" ID="CB1" Value="TAC">
            <SPAN STYLE=color:red ID="checkbox_error"></SPAN>
        </P>

        <P>&nbsp;</P>
        <INPUT TYPE="button" VALUE="  SUBMIT  " onClick="validate()">
        </FORM>

    </BODY>
</HTML>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You missed a capital letter on this line:

`len = document.frmone.payment.length;`

Should be `len = document.frmOne.payment.length;`

You should learn to use your browser's web inspector, it can help you easily spot this stuff.

Comment: Yes, thanks @Marco, you are right I corrected that mistake now - But the form is still not posting error message,  must be another error some where!

Answer (score 1):

There are 3 places where you need to change `frmone` to `frmOne`. One is as Marco pointed out.The other places are

```
if (document.frmOne.payment[i].checked){
                    payment = document.frmOne.payment[i].value;
                    break;
                }
```

Comment: Thanks @Srinivas - it works now, success. Feel like a  plum for not spotting errors my self. will have to look for a good code debugger to help my eyes. have a reputation point on me.